# XML Schema Unique together on two attributes in any order

Tags: xml, xsd, unique

I have a simple xml structure similar to what is outlined in question [XML Schema Unique Together on Two Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525353/xml-schema-unique-together-on-two-attributes), however I would like to make this unique in any order.

I have figured out how to make this unique together except if I reverse the values it doesn't work. I used

```
<xsd:element name="foo">
  ...
      <xsd:unique name="rowcol">
      <xsd:selector xpath="bar"/>
           <xsd:field xpath="@row"/>
           <xsd:field xpath="@column"/>
      </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>
```

For this scenario

```
<foo>
   <bar row="42" column="2"></bar>
   <bar row="42" column="3"></bar>
   <bar row="42" column="2"></bar>
   <bar row="3" column="42"></bar>
 </foo>
```

I would like the last 2 items to fail the uniqueness test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with XSD 1.0.

You can do it with an assertion in XSD 1.1. Keep your uniqueness constraint, and add

```
<xsd:assert test="not(some $x in bar, $y in bar[not($y is $x)] 
                      satisifies $x/@row = $y/@column 
                             and $x/@column = $y/@row)"/>
```